# Oracle descending order with exception

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select status from table where 'condition' order by status desc
```

returns:

```
T
R
P
O
N
C
```

Is it possible to display 'P' always at top and rest of them in normal descending order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select status from table where 'condition' 
order by case when status = 'P' then 0 else 1 end, status desc
```

Comment: Works fine, Thanks alot.